# Matplotlib - color as third variable for already normalized data - not in grayscale

Tags: python, arrays, variables, matplotlib, colors

I've searched for this but haven't been able to find an answer - how do you implement the color as the third variable in matplotlib if your data is already normalized? My data is in the range 0-1 and thus this produces a graph in grayscale, but I would like one that fades from say, blue to yellow, with blue = 1, some sort of green for the values about 0.5 and yellow for values around 0.

My code currently reads:

```
    for line in lines:
    if line:
       x1.append(line.split()[0])
       y1.append(line.split()[1])
       z1.append(line.split()[4])
    xv = np.array(x1)
    yv = np.array(y1)
    zv = np.array(z1)

    plt.scatter(xv, yv, c=zv, cmap=?)
```

I've tried all sorts of variations, including the no_norm but the best I can still get is the grayscale plot... 
I don't think using vmin and vmax is going down the right route, and I've also tried doing

```
    cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('autumn')
    plt.scatter(xv, yv, c=cmap(zv))
```

but this produces the error:

```
     TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('S11') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Thanks very much in advance,
Anna

Comment: `plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='YlGnBu')` should do what you want

Comment: or just passing `cmap` with out calling it.

Comment: Hm this still isn't working for me, I'm using matplotlib version 1.4.3 and python 2.7.5 if this makes any difference. Here is the entirety of my code:

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    infile = open("filename", "r")
    lines=infile.readlines()
    x1 =[]
    y1=[]
    z1= []
    for line in lines:
        line=line.strip()
        if line:
            x1.append(line.split()[0])
       y1.append(line.split()[1])
       z1.append(line.split()[4])
    xv = np.array(x1)
    yv = np.array(y1)
    zv = np.array(z1)

    plt.scatter(xv, yv, c=zv, cmap='YlGnBu')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading **@tcaswell**'s comment, I found [this page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html). This solutions seems way more elegant. You can pick the cmap you want from the page and use it like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = range(11)
ys = [0] * 11
colors = [ i * 0.1 for i in range(11) ] 

plt.scatter(xs, ys, s=600, c = colors, cmap='YlGnBu')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html <- that is actually a better reference

Answer (score 1):

@tcaswell and @Sait answered the question, but just to expand on why the cmap wasn't working for my data, is that c needs to be an array of floats, whereas I just had it has a np.array for my z values.

Thus I edited my code to add in the following:

```
    xv = np.array(x1)
    yv = np.array(y1)
    zv = np.array(z1).astype(np.float)
    sc = plt.scatter(xv, yv, c=zv, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap=cm.getmap('YlGnBu'))

    plt.colorbar(sc)
    plt.show()
```